# OS X thinks that my folder (with .suffix at the end) is related to some App

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, file-association

I've named a folder with .suffix which already bound to one of Mac applications. And that is the problem when I'm trying to open this folder through the Finder.

I've delete the App related to .suffix.

So how do I revert the system back to the state when Finder opens my folder correctly?

(OS version 10.8.2)

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree ~/045.Book/
kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "com.apple.ibooksauthor.pkgbook",
    "com.apple.package",
    "public.directory",
    "public.item",
    "public.composite-content",
    "public.content"
)
```

But when I open it, Terminal App started.

See the list of Info.plist with .book extension handling in it:

```
find /Applications -type f -name Info.plist -exec grep -i -nH -e "\.book" {} \;
/Applications/Calendar.app/Contents/Info.plist:117:             <string>com.apple.ical.bookmark</string>
/Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/NetServices/Bundles/BookService.NetService/Contents/Info.plist:18:    <string>com.apple.BookService</string>
/Applications/Reminders.app/Contents/Info.plist:55:             <string>com.apple.ical.bookmark.todo</string>
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist:581:           <string>com.apple.safari.bookmark</string>
```

Comment: Empty the trash as well. You might also need to log out and back in, or restart your computer. You can always right-click the folder and select "Show Package Contents" as a workaround.

Comment: Another fix could be to run: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`

Comment: I've done all this, but now OSX want's to open AAA.book dir with Terminal app!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the Info.plist folder is in some other place than below /Applications.

The following tool is very handy to find out about current file associations etc. and to reset them: http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/

See also http://www.guidingtech.com/20779/set-remove-default-file-associations-mac/

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.